# How to use a vpn to connect to different networks according to the authentication domain?

Tags: vpn

How to use a vpn to connect to different networks according to the domain of authentication? How would that work? For example, if a person signed in with a user @aettr.edu, they entered the network independently of that institution. PS: The main radius can query the adjacent radius.

[image: Network diagram]

Comment: You need to provide more details about technology you use. In short radius servers are capable to return answers depending on queries parameters

Comment: For vpn I was thinking of using L2TP as it is not necessary to install any additional programs. Yes, the radius server can return different information according to the query parameters. My problem is how I do it for an ex: ASA or a Mikrotik (preference), recognize these parameters coming from the radius and connect me to the correct vlan automatically, without having to configure routes on the client side.

Comment: Do you actually want to protect network 2 from users from group 1? ASA have VLAN mappings based on Radius or LDAP responses. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/asa_90_cli_config/ref_extserver.html